# how to show a number into brazilian number but it should works as normal number for calculation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to convert the number 123,123,214.93 into 123.123.214,93 (Brazilian currency) only for display purposes is there any way or method by which I can do this.

I have tried to convert the numbers using a function inside that first im adding the (.) after 3 numbers and in place of decimal point (.) im using (,) and then for any calculation im converting it again using replaceAll('.',',')  JavaScript, but I want any genuine method or a genuine way for converting the number into Brazilian currency

Comment: Consider using [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/format)?

Comment: You should store the number as a number but only display it as a string. You shouldn't have to convert it back to number after displaying

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
const number = 123123214.93;
const formattedCurrency = number.toLocaleString('pt-BR', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'BRL'
});

console.log(formattedCurrency); // Outputs: R$ 123.123.214,93
```